# Signing a jar recursively

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have an executable jar which contains another jar.

1. When I sign the main jar and run it using javaws it throws an error that some resources are not signed. Is there any way I can sign all jar inside this jar recursively.
2. Do I need to sign jnlp file as well because for a different signed jar it throws an error that jnlp is not signed with same certificate as other jar.

Comment: SO is not a help desk but a Q&A site.  Please decide which question to ask for **this thread** and split the other off into a new question.

Comment: You've misread the error message mentioned in your second question.

Comment: in my opinion these question made sense to put in one post as they are related and people might get these issues together.

The error message is something like that may not be exact. the exact error message was "jnlp not signed by same certificate"